# How to limit number of store results in grid ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

Can you help me guys. I have problems with using loadRawData. My paging toolbar in grid views count of all records and pages, but it can't switch pages. Also grid views all records from my store, it above 1000. 
On page click, next or previous click displayed error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"
```

My store is here:

```
var objStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    //model: 'objModel',
    storeId: 'allObjects',
    autoLoad: false,
    pageSize: 30,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'nm',
        direction: 'asc'
        }],
    fields:[
        {name: 'nm', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax'
    },
    loadRawData: function(data,append){
        var me = this,
        result = me.proxy.reader.read(data),
        records = result.records;

        if (result.success) {
            me.totalCount = objArr.totalItemsCount;
            me.currentPage = 1;
            me.loadRecords(records,{addRecords: append});
            me.fireEvent('load',me,records,true);
        }
    }
});
```

My grid:

```
 var pagingTb = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
    store: objStore,
    displayInfo: true,
    displayMsg: 'Показано  {0} - {1} из {2}', // формат инфо
    loadPage: function(page) {
        var me = this;

        me.currentPage = page;

        me.read({
            page: page,
            start: (page - 1) * me.pageSize,
            limit: me.pageSize,
            addRecords: !me.clearOnPageLoad
        });
    }
});

var objGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
id: 'grid',
store: objStore,
height: 500,
columns: [
        {header:'№',xtype: 'rownumberer',width:40,style:'text-align:center;'},
        {text: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id', width: 50,style:'text-align:center;'},
        {text:'Объект', dataIndex: 'nm', width: 300,style:'text-align:center;'}
    ],
bbar: pagingTb
});
```

My request in button's listener:

```
listeners:{
            click:{
                    fn: function() {
                        request=Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'myurl',
                        success: function(response, opts){
                        objArr = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('allObjects');
                        store.loadRawData(objArr.items, true);
                        },
                        failure: function(response, opts) {
                        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                            }
                        });
                    }
            }
        }
```